# IllegalAccessException while annotation's method invocation via reflection (OpenJDK 11)

Tags: java, reflection, java-11, openjdk-11

I'm trying to create a custom annotations processing mechanism (retrieving annotation values and passing them into field's constructor), e.g.

```java
@Find(by = CSS, locator = "[data-qa=username]")
private Input username;
```

Well, different reflective operations had perfectly worked for me in JDK 8. However, I'm not able to acess annotation's methods anymore (in Java 11) due to the following exception (note that there's a jOOR module used behind the scene, but the same issue happens if I use a pure Java reflection):

```java
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.joor.Reflect (in module org.jooq.joor) cannot access class com.sun.proxy.jdk.proxy2.$Proxy9 (in module jdk.proxy2) because module jdk.proxy2 does not export com.sun.proxy.jdk.proxy2 to module org.jooq.joor
org.joor.ReflectException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.joor.Reflect (in module org.jooq.joor) cannot access class com.sun.proxy.jdk.proxy2.$Proxy9 (in module jdk.proxy2) because module jdk.proxy2 does not export com.sun.proxy.jdk.proxy2 to module org.jooq.joor
    at org.jooq.joor/org.joor.Reflect.on(Reflect.java:896)
    at org.jooq.joor/org.joor.Reflect.call(Reflect.java:563)
    at org.jooq.joor/org.joor.Reflect.call(Reflect.java:516)
    at io.github.sskorol.reflection/io.github.sskorol.reflection.testcases.ReflectionTests.lambda$shouldAccessAnnotationValues$5(ReflectionTests.java:27)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:361)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.fillBuffer(StreamSpliterators.java:210)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:161)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:300)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.WhileOps$1$1.accept(WhileOps.java:99)
    at one.util.streamex@0.7.0/one.util.streamex.StreamEx$2.tryAdvance(StreamEx.java:2741)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:550)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:517)
    at one.util.streamex@0.7.0/one.util.streamex.AbstractStreamEx.toArray(AbstractStreamEx.java:344)
    at one.util.streamex@0.7.0/one.util.streamex.AbstractStreamEx.toList(AbstractStreamEx.java:1186)
    at io.github.sskorol.reflection/io.github.sskorol.reflection.testcases.ReflectionTests.shouldAccessAnnotationValues(ReflectionTests.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng@7.0.0/org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.joor.Reflect (in module org.jooq.joor) cannot access class com.sun.proxy.jdk.proxy2.$Proxy9 (in module jdk.proxy2) because module jdk.proxy2 does not export com.sun.proxy.jdk.proxy2 to module org.jooq.joor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:558)
    at org.jooq.joor/org.joor.Reflect.on(Reflect.java:892)
    ... 79 more
```

I created a [sample project](https://github.com/sskorol/reflective-access) to reproduce the issue (only those part which fails on the annotation method's invocation).

It seems like some JDK internals should be opened/exported in Gradle config. Would be greatly appreciated if you can point me what exactly is missing to resolve this ussue.

**UPDATE:**

Here are key code snippets:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Find {

    By by();

    String locator();

    String name() default "";
}
```

```java
public class LoginPage {

    @Find(by = By.CSS, locator = "[data-qa=username]", name = "username input")
    private Input username;
}
```

```java
var values = StreamEx.iterate(LoginPage.class, (UnaryOperator<Class<?>>) Class::getSuperclass)
    .takeWhile(page -> !page.equals(Object.class))
    .flatMap(page -> stream(page.getDeclaredFields()))
    .filter(field -> field.isAnnotationPresent(Find.class))
    .map(field -> field.getAnnotation(Find.class))
    .flatMap(annotation -> StreamEx.of(annotation.annotationType().getDeclaredMethods())
        .sortedBy(Method::getName)
        .map(method -> on(annotation).call(method.getName()).get()))
    .toList();
```

And here's a sequence from jOOR (when `call` method is getting invoked -> `on(annotation).call(method.getName()).get()`):

- [fist call](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR/blob/master/jOOR/src/main/java/org/joor/Reflect.java#L515-L517)
- [second call](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR/blob/master/jOOR/src/main/java/org/joor/Reflect.java#L556-L576)
- [last call, which causes exception](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOR/blob/master/jOOR/src/main/java/org/joor/Reflect.java#L883-L898)

Comment: Can you paste in your code that uses reflection as that might be easier to discuss? I'll bet the issue is that you (and jOOR) have obtain the Method for the method in the proxy implementation class when you should be invoking the proxy's method using the Method for the method in the interface that it implements.

Comment: @AlanBateman updated description

Comment: Replace `on(annotation).call(method.getName()).get()` with `on(Find.class, annotation) .call(method.getName()).get()`, to force the use of the interface rather than actual implementation class.

Comment: @Holger we can't use `on(Find.class, annotation)`, as it's private. Moreover, internally `on(annotation)` does the same thing, as it takes a type and passes it to overloaded method. Even if we use `onClass(Find.class)`, it's impossible to use `call` without creating an instance via `onClass(Find.class).create().call(...)`. But it won't work either, as we can't init annotation.

Comment: Wow, so this Reflection library did try really hard to make this fail. You already have the `Method` object but can’t specify it and you already know the actual lookup class but can’t specify it. I’m wondering if this is just an oversight and should be public. However, since you already have the necessary `Method` object, why not call it directly like `.map(method -> {  try {  return method.invoke(annotation);  } catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) {  throw new IllegalStateException(ex);  }  }))` without using the 3rd party library which creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @Holger well, I like this lib as it wraps reflection API, so that we can avoid ugly and verbose syntax with tons of throwables. It's really nice to use it within stream API. However, in this particular case, it seems reasonable to use a raw reflection API, as you suggested. `.map(method -> Try.of(() -> method.invoke(annotation)).getOrElse(() -> null))` did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: For clarification, `on(annotation)` does the equivalent of `on(annotation.getClass(), annotation)` which will end up at a non-exported implementation class whereas `on(Find.class, annotation)` or `on(annotation.annotationType(), annotation)` used the annotation interface, if the method was public. It’s a common problem with reflection code to look up a method on a nonpublic implementation class that actually implements or overrides an accessible method of a public class. The Reflect class tried to workaround the problem by calling `setAccessible(true)` which now is forbidden in certain cases.

Comment: Just to add that the reason that the proxy class is encapsulated here is because the interface is encapsulated. The proxy should have been generated into an unnamed module if the interface wasn't encapsulated.